# Legend height seems to have an impact on pie size

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart with a legend (layout=vertical). Unfortunately the legend height has an impact to the pie. This means the more items the chart has the smaller the pie chart. Also the container height seems also have an impact.
My aim is to have a fixed pie size and the wrapper container should grow with the legend height. Is this possible? How?
Here is the js part:

```
$(function () {
var chart;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                        type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        legend:{
          align: 'center',
            enabled: true,
          layout: 'vertical',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                ['Chrome',  12.8],
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7],
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                ['Chrome',  12.8],
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7],
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                ['Chrome',  12.8],
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7],
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                ['Chrome',  12.8],
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

And here is the HTML part:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: you can use [legend.maxHeight](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.maxHeight) check http://jsfiddle.net/c4j9yn9e/

Answer (score 0):

You can get legend height, add it to the actual chart height and set a new height using `setSize` function on load event. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#setSize

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5hjwtvz0/